# Gender of the subject in a sentence starting with "und"

Tags: gender

If I have a main sentence like this:

> Den Fehler zu ignorieren

and I want to connect another one with "und" in that way:

> und xx zu löschen

Which pronoun fits best at the position of xx? *Es* or *er* (as the subjective is masculine)? Or maybe the article *den* (as the subject is masculine in accusative)?

Comment: "Den Fehler zu ignorieren und *diesen* zu löschen" is also a possibility. "Diesen" is a demonstrative pronoun, which function is to represent a noun.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is "und _ihn_ zu löschen", or, if there is nothing between the first and the second part, "und zu löschen". But, as @Takkat pointed out, you cannot delete an _error_, you can only delete an _error message_ (eine _Fehlermeldung_).

Comment: Ein Hauptsatz kann meines Wissens alleine stehen, was für obigen Textschnipsel nicht zutrifft.

Comment: "Den Fehler zu ignorieren" is not a main sentence at all, it is just an infinitive group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would simply write

> "und zu löschen"

except you want to delete anything else like some data, the I would write:

> "Den Fehler zu ignorieren und die Daten zu löschen"

If you really want to add a pronoun there, the best fit would probably be "ihn" but I think it's not really necessary

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand that there are better ways to write it but I couldn't really think of a better example that is necessary to keep the pronoun. I believe "ihn" was the answer I wanted. =)

Comment: Well, *ihn* is semantically wrong because you can't delete an error, even less after you ignored it (you could delete the error *message* however).